# Tenancy for Laravel - tinker throws up migration files when creating a new tenant

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I've taken over a project from a prev dev, and I'm trying to understand the tenancy for laravel package, we've past the point of no return on the project to use a new package and to be fair the package and domain is working well for the created subdomain put in by the previous dev, but when I use tinker to create a new tenant and domain, as described in the quick start doc, tinker creates the db, creates the domain and tenant but it seems to fetch a migration file from one of the subdomains too?  Anyone every came across this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your migration files have the same class name, which is not allowed.

Try using anonymous classes instead and you won't run into this problem. This is possible since laravel 8.37

Instead of

```php
class CreateAgreementSubTypesTable extends Migration { ... }
```

write

```php
return new class extends Migration { ... }; // semi colon is important.
```

Comment: Can you get away with doing anonymous classes for every migration file??

Comment: Yes, you can. It's the preferred way now, precisely because of the possible class name collision

Comment: Don't have the rep to give it the upvote but thanks very much